# What is the type of return value of `date::floor<days>` function?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm using date.h cpp lib (https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)

It's easy to define function which receives a time point:

```
void startAtTime(system_clock::time_point time) {
    ....
}
```

However I don't understand how to define a function that will receive dates trimmed to days instead of full timestamps. Something like this:

```
void startOnDay(/* day_point */ day) {
    ....
}
```

This is how I do it right now in all functions that require `days`:

```
void startOnDay(system_clock::time_point day) {
    auto startOfDay = date::floor<days>(day);
    ...
}
```

But I want to verify that `day` is `day` during the compilation time.
Type signature of floor makes no sense to me:

[image: floor return type]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`floor<days>` is overloaded on `duration` and `time_point`:

```
template<class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>
  constexpr
  ToDuration
  floor(const duration<Rep, Period>& d);

template<class ToDuration, class Clock, class Duration>
  constexpr
  time_point<Clock, ToDuration>
  floor(const time_point<Clock, Duration>& tp);
```

As `day` in your example code is a `time_point`, you're using the second overload.  And the return type will be

```
time_point<system_clock, days>
```

Note that there is a type alias for this type called `sys_days`.

Also note that `floor` is now part of C++17 (and forward), and `days` and `sys_days` became part of the chrono library in C++20.

You might find it helpful that `sys_days` (the return type of `startOfDay` in your example) is implicitly convertible to `year_month_day` which has getters for the `year`, `month` and `day` fields.  `year_month_day` is also now in C++20.

```
void startOnDay(system_clock::time_point day) {
    auto startOfDay = date::floor<days>(day);
    date::year_month_day ymd = startOfDay;
    cout << ymd.year() << '\n';
    cout << ymd.month() << '\n';
    cout << ymd.day() << '\n';
    ...
}
```

> However I don't understand how to define a function that will receive dates trimmed to days instead of full timestamps. Something like this:

```
void startOnDay(/* day_point */ day) {
    ....
}
```

You could do this by making the parameter type `time_point<system_clock, days>`, or equivalently `sys_days`:

```
void startOnDay(date::sys_days day) {
    ....
}
```

(`std::chrono::sys_days` in C++20)

*Note:* `time_point`s associated with `system_clock` have type alias that are prefixed with `sys_`.  All such `time_point`s have the semantics of [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):  A duration measured since (or before) 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC neglecting leap seconds.  This is a very close approximation to UTC, and not to be confused with your local time.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciate your work on `date.h`